# I was installing create-react-app on vs code but due to internet issue installation stopped and when I am installing this error is coming

Tags: javascript, reactjs

PS E:\web development\React> npx create-react-app testtutorial
Need to install the following packages:
create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y) ok
npm ERR! canceled

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-11T15_51_38_850Z-debug.log

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: could you please share with us the commands timeline? I did not get the phase between internet issue and installation phase. Moreover, do you have any issues if you try again the command in a new folder?

Comment: Same error is coming if I am opening in different folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.